# Implement Generic FIFO

Tags: dml-lang

I am looking into implementing a FIFO that can hopefully be reused in multiple devices.

The FIFO template shall expose these methods `push` `pop` and `len`. I want the size of the FIFO to be defined as a parameter and I want the type the FIFO holds to be any type of standard integer types (uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64, int8, int16, int32 and int64). Pushing a 64-bit integer into a 8-bit FIFO shall cause truncation. The FIFO shall also support checkpointing.

I started with this code but it does not compile:

```
template fifo {
    param fifo_size;
    saved uint64 buf[fifo_size];
}
```

Comment: This answer might be related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020250/dmlc-throws-unknown-identifier-without-using-if/75020646#75020646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are only a very small, restricted set of types you need to support, then creating a separate FIFO template for each type may be advisable (using [`#if` to ensure the `buf` declaration works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020250/dmlc-throws-unknown-identifier-without-using-if)). Such an implementation would be the easiest to understand, while still providing the greatest number of benefits for users of the templates -- its only cost is the excessive boiler-plate needed to define the templates.

However, there is an alternate approach leveraging [pseudo-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75021982/is-there-an-equivalent-for-ctemplate-typename-t-in-dml) which allows you to write a template that scales up to any number of supported types, and has almost all of the same benefits as creating duplicate templates for each type.
Here is how such a `fifo` template would look using that approach:

```
template fifo {
    // Maximum size of the FIFO
    param fifo_size;

    // Any expression, whose type dictates the type of the elements of the FIFO
    param fifo_type_carrier;

    // Internal
    saved uint32 fifo_buf_start;

    // Partially internal: should not be modified by the user
    saved uint32 len;

    // This saved declaration relies on instance-specific information;
    // #if (true) is thus needed to prevent DMLC from trying to make it
    // a member of the the template type
    #if (true) {
        saved typeof(fifo_type_carrier) fifo_buf[fifo_size];
    }

    // Since their signatures are instance-specific, 'push' and 'pop' can't be
    // members of `fifo`'s template type.

    // Throws if the FIFO is full
    method push(typeof(fifo_type_carrier) elem) throws {
        if (len >= fifo_size) throw;
        fifo_buf[(fifo_buf_start + len++) % fifo_size] = elem;
    }

    // Throws if the FIFO is empty
    method pop() -> (typeof(fifo_type_carrier)) throws {
        if (len == 0) throw;
        local typeof(fifo_type_carrier) elem = fifo_buf[fifo_buf_start];
        fifo_buf_start = (fifo_buf_start + 1) % fifo_size;
        --len;
        return elem;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
group a_uint64_fifo is fifo {
    param fifo_type_carrier = *cast(NULL, uint64 *);
    param fifo_size = 32;
}
```

The greatest downside of `fifo` compared to duplicated, type-specific templates is that `push` and `pop` are not members of the template type. However, this actually addressable -- you can create a child template of `fifo` for a specific type, and declare `push` and `pop` to be `shared` in that template -- making them members of the child template's template type.

For example:

```
template fifo_uint64 is fifo {
    param fifo_type_carrier = *cast(NULL, uint64 *);
    shared method push(uint64 elem) throws;
    shared method pop() -> (uint64) throws;
}
```

Example usage:

```
group a_uint64_fifo is fifo_uint64 {
    param fifo_size = 32;
}

method m() -> (uint64) throws {
    local fifo_uint64 x = cast(a_uint64_fifo, fifo_uint64);
    // allowed
    x.push(4);
    return x.pop();
}
```

As strange as it may seem to have non-`shared` methods defined by a parent template be declared `shared` by a child template, it is actually perfectly allowed by DMLC. You can do the same thing with parameters, too -- an untyped `param` declared by a parent template can be made a typed `param` of a child template. This pattern is called "late shared", in want of a better name.

The one benefit the above lacks compared to FIFO templates with duplicated implementations is that the underlying implementations of `pop` and `push` aren't `shared` (even if the methods themselves are declared `shared` by a child template). What this means is that the C functions for them are generated for every object that instantiates the template -- which could inflate compilation times if a particular DML model has a *lot* of such objects. In contrast, with templates defined by duplicating code, you could make the implementations of `push` and `pop` shared (although not without a small wrapper method to gain access to the `fifo_buf`, whose implementation can't be shared). In theory, such a template would scale better with growing number of instances than one based on the type-generic `fifo`.

Comment: Since the number of types is small, perhaps the type carrier can be hidden? like,
```
param int_size default 64;
param type_carrier = *(int_size == 64 #? cast(NULL, uint64 *) #: int_size = 32 #? cast(NULL, uint32 *) #: int_size = 16 #? cast(NULL, uint16 *) #: int_siize = 8 #? cast(NULL, uint8 *) : undefined);
```